# Control the ethernet shield with Chrome and Safari

Tags: ethernet

I am trying to communicate with ethernet shield. When I enter the IP in Chrome the job is done (simply an LED turns off and on with IP/$1 and IP/$2) but with Safari it is not. Any idea what the difference is?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I forgot to complete the `client.println` with a newline (`\n`).

Comment: Can you explain why this would happen? `println` should already insert two newlines—why do you need two?